# How to use textbox textChanged property with background worker to fill datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

in my form i have a textbox, background worker and a data grid view. using the textbox(TextChanged property) i want to fatch data using the background worker and fill matching data in the data grid view as i type.

here is what i have tried out.

```
 private void txtSearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
   {
   backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
   }
   backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();///Runs the background worker     
 }
```

```
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {                
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from Games where Name like '%" + txtSearchBox.Text + "%'", con);
                    
                    da.Fill(ds, "GameID");                    
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
                }  
        }
```

```
        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            SimilarData.DataSource = ds.Tables["GameID"].DefaultView;
        }
```

With that am getting this error.
ErrorSystem.InvalidOperationExceptoin:This Background worker is currently busyand and not run multiple tasks concurrently.

What do i do?

Comment: I'd suggest to run the worker when you press `Enter` key or in a button click event. This is too much. For now call `if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) return;` or disable the text box and enable it again in the `RunWorkerCompleted`. Consider the suggestion.

Comment: i have tried that is only searching once, if the text changes in the text box and i press the a search buttton its drawing a blank data grid view.

Comment: Don't access the `txtSearchBox.Text` in the `DoWork` event. Pass it or back it in a class field. Also, you should use parameters to create the command, not string concatenation. Also 2, get rid of the `try..catch` block and handle the exceptions if any in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. There is `e.Error` and `e.Cancelled` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would be open to a simpler approach than using `BackgroundWorker` what I would suggest is making an `async` handler for the `textbox.TextChanged` event that takes note of the keystroke count going in before awaiting a "cooling off" period for rapid typing. If the count is the same before and after awaiting this delay it indicates that typing is sufficiently stable to perform a query.

[image: screenshot]

I have mocked this out using `sqlite-net-pcl` for the sake of expediency. The DGV is bound to a `DataSource` that is a `BindingList<Game>`. The `OnLoad` override of `MainForm` initializes the `DataGridView`, then whatever database server you're using. The last thing is to subscribe to the `TextChanged` event and this is where all the where all the action takes place.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    initDGV();
    initSQL();
    textBox.TextChanged += onTextBoxTextChanged;
}
BindingList<Game> DataSource = new BindingList<Game>();
// Comparing the awaited count to the total count so that
// the DGV isn't visually updated until all queries have run.
int _queryCount = 0;
```

---

**`TextBox.TextChanged` event handler (async)**

```
private async void onTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
    {
        return;
    }
    _queryCount++;
    var queryCountB4 = _queryCount;
    List<Game> recordset = null;
    var captureText = textBox.Text;

    // Settling time for rapid typing to cease.
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));

    // If keypresses occur in rapid succession, only
    // respond to the latest one after a settling timeout.
    if (_queryCount.Equals(queryCountB4))
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var cnx = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                var sql = $"SELECT * FROM games WHERE GameID LIKE '{captureText}%'";
                recordset = cnx.Query<Game>(sql);
            }
        });
        DataSource.Clear();
        foreach (var game in recordset)
        {
            DataSource.Add(game);
        }
    }
    else Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for all pending queries to complete");
}
```

---

**DataGridView**

```
private void initDGV()
{
    dataGridView.DataSource = DataSource;
    dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    DataSource.Add(new Game { GameID = "Generate Columns" });
    dataGridView
        .Columns[nameof(Game.GameID)]
        .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    dataGridView
        .Columns[nameof(Game.Created)]
        .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    DataSource.Clear();
}
```

---

**Database**

```
private void initSQL()
{
    // For testing, start from scratch every time
    if (File.Exists(ConnectionString)) File.Delete(ConnectionString);
    using (var cnx = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        cnx.CreateTable<Game>();
        cnx.Insert(new Game { GameID = "Awe" });
        cnx.Insert(new Game { GameID = "Abilities" });
        cnx.Insert(new Game { GameID = "Abscond" });
        cnx.Insert(new Game { GameID = "Absolve" });
        cnx.Insert(new Game { GameID = "Absolute" });
    }
}
```

---

**Game**

```
[Table("games")]
class Game
{
    [PrimaryKey, Browsable(false)]
    public string Guid { get; set; } = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper();
    public string GameID { get; set; }
    private DateTime _created = DateTime.Now.Date;
    public string Created 
    {
        get => _created.ToShortDateString();
        set
        {
            if(DateTime.TryParse(value, out DateTime dt))
            {
                _created = dt.Date;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/populate-dgv-on-thread.git) this sample.